# Division return 0 all the time

Tags: solidity

I would like to do a division in my solidity smart contract but the result is always 0, I found some stuff on stackoverflow about this problem, this is working with [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738640/division-in-ethereum-solidity?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but not with SafeMath, someone know why?

```
    uint amount1 = 100;
    uint amount2 = 142;

    result = SafeMath.div(amount1, amount2); // return 0
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution right after I submitted this question.

100/142 = 0.7042 which is a decimal less than 1. Because solidity only works with integer, I'm getting only the initial 0.

To get the right result, I did:
100 * 10000 / 142 = 7042 which is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: 0.7042 is "decimal < 0" it is "decimal < 1"!!!

Comment: And BTW, `SafeMath.div` is a waste of time, just use `/` (Zeppelin too, will realize it at some point and get rid of it).

Comment: But what about the overflow and security?

Comment: There cannot be any overflow in division, and the only "security" issue here is division by 0, which will trigger an exception in either case (whether you use `div` or `/`).

Comment: Oh yes you are right but I prefer to still use it to keep a consistent code